# Supremum of $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log x_i$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Find supremum of:

> $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log x_i$

in the following set:

> $D=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\ge0 , \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1\}$. Note: we define $x_i \log x_i=0$ when $x_i=0$

It's easy to see that $f\in C^1(D)$. However, I've been struggling to present $D$ as zeros of a function in order to use lagrange multipliers.

The natural function to pick is $g(x)=1- \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. However , this function disregard the constraint that $x_1,\dots,x_n\ge0$.

Comment: I think you should treat nonnegativity $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ as an abstract set constraint $x \in A$ (for $A$ the convex set of all nonnegative vectors) so then you just have one Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ for minimizing $f(x) + \lambda g(x)$ subject to $x \in A$.

Comment: @Michael What do you mean? If I disregard nonnegativity, I get a set which is not compact.

Comment: There are various Lagrange multiplier results, it is not clear what one you are wanting to use.  A convenient choice is to use Lagrange multipliers with abstract convex set constraints, as I suggest above.  If you do not know that, then just define additional constraints $h_i(x)$, and additional Lagrange multipliers $\mu_i$, to enforce $x_i\geq 0$.  That will "formally" get you the same answer, but is not quite good, since your $f(x)$ is not defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Michael How can I define such a constraint?

Comment: It is not clear what your phrase "such a constraint" refers to. My first comment shows how to define the abstract set constraint. Notice that the problem formulated in my first comment is separable over the individual $x_i$ variables.

Comment: @Michael I meant non-negativity constraints. If I use lagrange multipliers without addressing the non-negativity constraints, the set will not be compact and thus, maximum will not necessarily be obtained in that region. So I need to explain why is the maximum obtained. How can it be done?

Comment: What set do you require to be compact?  It seems you are trying to plug into an unstated theorem, I cannot follow.  And who said anything about not addressing the non-negativity constraints?

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to use the method of lagrange multipliers. Please see here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#:~:text=The%20Lagrange%20multiplier%20theorem%20states,gradients%20of%20the%20constraints%20(at)

Comment: But you agree that $f(x)$ is not defined over all $\mathbb{R}^n$, correct?  So, how are you going to use the method there?  And again, who said anything about neglecting the nonnegativity constraints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109617/discussion-between-bulgali-and-michael).

Comment: You gave a mysterious comment in chat "f(x) is indeed defined over $\mathbb{R}^n$."  It is not clear how you are evaluating the $\log()$ function at negative numbers.  What is the value of $\log(-1)$? I also disagree with your comment in your question "It is easy to see $f \in C_1(D)$," since the derivatives at $x_1=0$ are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective function is $f:[0, \infty)^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ rather than $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and so the results on the Wikipedia link that you provide do not directly apply.
A more general Lagrange multiplier statement for functions defined on arbitrary domains is this:

---

Assume:

- $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an arbitrary set (possibly nonconvex).
- $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary functions  (possibly nonconvex and nondifferentiable).

**Theorem**: Fix $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x^* \in X$ solves the following problem:
\begin{align}
\mbox{Minimize:} & \quad f(x) + \lambda g(x) \\
\mbox{Subject to:} & \quad x \in X 
\end{align}
Then $x^*$ also solves this problem:
\begin{align}
\mbox{Minimize:} & \quad f(x)   \\
\mbox{Subject to:} & \quad g(x) = g(x^*)\\
& \quad x \in X 
\end{align}

This statement is Theorem II.3 (on page 13) in these notes and the proof is easy:

http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/network-optimization-notes.pdf

---

So for your problem define $X = \{(x_1, ..., x_n) : x_i\geq 0\quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}\}$ and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as you already do. For your problem, given any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, it is easy to minimize $f(x) + \lambda g(x)$ subject to $x \in X$. The problem separates over each of the $n$ variables. You can get an analytical solution $x^*_{\lambda}$ (in terms of $\lambda$) that you can adjust to ensure $g(x^*_{\lambda})$ matches the desired constraint.